# How to run Core data tasks in background in swiftUI app?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I've read that Core data tasks should be kept out of the main thread in order to prevent freezing the UI. I've recently had problems in my Multiplatform swiftUI app with a laggy UI, and was wondering how I could make all my Core data stuff run in the background.

This is my PersistenceController, from a hacking with swift article:

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Main")

        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }

        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func save() {
        let context = container.viewContext

        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use these functions in both classes for my Core data objects to change stuff in Core data:

```
static func add(name: String, puzzle: String, notes: String? = nil, order: Int, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let newInstance = Instance(context: context)
    
    newInstance.name = name
    newInstance.puzzle = puzzle
    newInstance.notes = notes
    newInstance.order = Int16(order)
    
    PersistenceController.shared.save()
}

static func delete(_ instance: Instance, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    context.delete(instance)
    
    PersistenceController.shared.save()
}

static func edit(_ instance: Instance, name: String? = nil, puzzle: String? = nil, notes: String? = nil, order: Int? = nil, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    if name != nil {
        instance.name = name!
    }
    if puzzle != nil {
        instance.puzzle = puzzle!
    }
    if notes != nil {
        instance.notes = notes!
    }
    if order != nil {
        instance.order = Int16(order!)
    }
    
    PersistenceController.shared.save()
}
```

(I have 2 entities, with a 1-to-many relationship. Both have these functions, just a bit different in the other)

I just use a simple FetchRequest to access the Core data objects:

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: Instance.entity(),
    sortDescriptors:
        [
            NSSortDescriptor(
                keyPath: \Instance.order,
                ascending: true)
        ]
) private var instances: FetchedResults<Instance>
```

An example of where core data slows down my UI is here:

```
withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
    stopwatch.stop()
}
addSolve(time: stopwatch.secondsElapsed)
```

Stopping the stopwatch normally has a smooth animation, but creating the new object and saving it to Core data causes some lag and sometimes makes the animation not smooth.

So what do I need to change to make core data work in the background and not interfere with my UI? Is there any edit I can make just to the PersistenceController so that I don't have to explicitly tell it to run in the background every time I do anything with core data? Or would I just be able to include any code for running in the background inside my add, edit, and delete functions?

Thanks!

Comment: as a suggestion use persistentCointainer.performBackgroundTask { context in 
//Your background operation w CoreData, you could use a completion to callback when your task is finished if you need
}

Comment: How to do this is explained in the [Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext) section of the documentation. if you wish to offload processing from the main queue you will need to specify `NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType` when creating the MOC, and use `perform(_:)` explicitly. You can also nest `perform(_:)` which can also help in breaking up work.